# Azure AD B2C: Set default value of custom attribute

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to set a default value for a custom attribute in Azure AD B2C?

I have an boolean attribute which indicates if a user has signed all agreements. The users will be created by Microsoft Graph API and I want to predifine the value for this attribute, so that I don't have to set it when the user is created.

Thank you in forward!

Best regards
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not supported by AAD B2C currently.

No matter whether you use Microsoft Graph or User flow / Custom policy, the custom attribute should be set when the the user is created into the AAD, then the default value of custom attribute can be saved.

I don't think this is a difficult job. Just add one more line when [creating the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1):

```
{
    "extension_8adbe99219ca4e689a5030b5af068847_YesOrNo": true
}
```

Besides, from a design perspective, this custom attribute should be updated after the user signs the agreement. It seems that predefining its value at the time of user creation is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Yes, I know that this is a possible way. But if I set a default value directly in Azure AD B2C, then I have the control about this value. When the by Graph API connected systems has to set the value, I don't have the control wether the systems really do it because the other systems are not under my control.

Comment: @MatthiasWirth Unfortunately it's not supported currently. If you do have this requirement, you can post your idea on [B2C User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c). If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.